# Does NHibernate support referencing unique columns that are not the primary key?

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm afraid I may be asking a stupid question here, but my google-fu seems to be suffering.  Most RDBMS's support creating a foreign key referencing a unique key in another table that is not the primary key, but I can't seem to find a "how-to" on this for NHibernate.  I assume because everyone assumes it's stupid-easy.

Is this supported?  Are there any caveats?  What would an XML mapping look like for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand well your question, `property-ref` is what you're looking for

From Nhibernate docs ([5.1.12. Many-to-one](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone))

> property-ref (optional): the name of a property of the associated class that is joined to this foreign key. If not specified, the primary key of the associated class is used.

I personally don't know any caveats but [Ayende Rahien](http://ayende.com/blog/3938/nhibernate-mapping-many-to-one), an active member of NHibernate development team, strongly suggest to avoid this if possible. He doesn't say why, probably just because is ugly :)

Comment: doc lists the one caveat...The property-ref attribute should only be used for mapping legacy data where a foreign key refers to a unique key of the associated table other than the primary key.

Comment: @dotjoe: good point but the OP states that the field is unique for this case.